# Create a tree structure from nested Braces php

Tags: php, tree

I'm looking to create a tree structure from a string with nested braces. Has anyone done that? Source code editors that have code folding use that. I'm looking to do it in php,maybe with a regex?
Thanks

Comment: what does the string look like, what is the desired output, did you expect us to be psychic?

Comment: definitely *not* with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly depends on the contents of your string.
If you are very lucky,

```
json_decode(strtr($str, '{}', '[]'))
```

might work. Lucky means: your string is a valid JSON array, recursively containing anything except objects, with all square brackets replaced by braces, and with no braces in strings. E.g.:

```
$str = '{3.14, null, {1, "two", 3}, {{"4.1 A", "4.1 B"}, 4.2}, true}'
```

See also http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to do a bit of string processing to identify the children tree strings of the root node and parse them recursively to create the final tree.

For example, if the root tree string with nested braces is like 
"{1:AA{..child 1..}{..child 2..}{..child 3..}...{..child n..}}", you can first identify the children tree strings (child 1 to child n) and then parse the n sub-strings recursively until the final tree structure is constructed.

You can refer this link http://moderntone.blogspot.tw/2013/08/a-general-algorithm-for-creating-tree.html to a blog post that introduces about a general idea/algorithm for solving this kind of problem about creating a tree structure from a string with nested braces or parentheses.